# Consulta eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Realizando una consulta en eloquent, la cual me lista los registros de la tabla a que están relacionados con los registros de la tabla b, hasta allí bien.

Adicionalmente necesito que también liste los registros de a que no están relacionados en b. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿revisaste la documentación?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la documentación de Laravel menciona que la clase `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` posee un método llamado [doesntHave](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_doesntHave) que sería lo opuesto a `has`.

En tu caso podrías hacer la consulta que necesitas así:

```
$noRelated = MoldelA::doesntHave('ModelB')->get();
```

Comment: Listo!!!. Gracias por aclarar la duda.